# ¿Error al ejecutar npm run grunt default?

Tags: nodejs, npm, grunt

Tengo los siguientes archivos para la configuracion de GruntJS y asi pasar mis archivos js a archivos js.min

El archivo package.json:

```
  {
  "name": "grunt-primerospasos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Descripcion de mi primer proyecto en gruntjs",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://gitlab.com/jggj/grunt-primerospasos.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gruntJS"
  ],
  "author": "jggarcia",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/jggj/grunt-primerospasos/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/jggj/grunt-primerospasos#README",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^3.1.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

y el archivo Gruntfile.js, de esta forma:

```
    module.exports = function (grunt) {
    //Configuraciones del proyecto
    grunt.initConfig({
        //Conf Uglify
        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: false,
                compress: {
                    drop_console: true
                }
            },
            js: {
                files:[{
                    cwd: 'js/src/', //ruta de nuestro javascript fuente
                    expand: true,   //ingresar a las subcarpetas
                    src: '*.js'     //patrón relativo a cwd
                    dest: 'js/min/' //destino de los archivos compresos, minificados
                }]
            }
        }
    });

//Cargar grunt-contrib-uglify (plugin)
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

//Registrar la tarea default, esta ejecutara la tarea grunt uglify
grunt.registerTask('default',['uglify']);

};
```

Cuando ejecuto el comando npm run grunt default me da el siguiente error:

```
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\grunt-primerospasos\npm-debug.log
```

y al final no puedo convertir mis archivos js a minificados.
Cuál podra ser mi error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cuando ejecuto el comando npm run grunt default me da el siguiente error:

El comando que tienes que ejecutar es **grunt default**

> grunt default
>   Running "uglify:js" (uglify) task
>
> > No files created.
> >     Done.

Tambien te va a servir si ejecutas **grunt** , ya que ejecuta por defecto la tarea **default**

Comment: Me da siguiente mensaje: "grunt" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutables.

Comment: Eso es que no tienes el grunt-cli instalado o no esta en el path. ``npm install -g grunt-cli``

Comment: Por los datos que pones entiendo que estas siguiendo el tutorial de frontendlabs.io, sigue los pies a pues juntillas que no tiene perdida :D

Comment: Muchas gracias me salte ese pase, creyendo que ya lo habia instalado. Ya me funciono !

Answer (score 0):

Persona que no te ayude lo suficiente, tienes que editar de alguna manera este código:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

lo más seguro es que si corres `npm test` vas a ver ese texto y se va a salir de la terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que no tengas definido el script "start" como bien dice el error:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node your-script.js"
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que se necesita iniciar un server node para utilizar grunt, puedes echar un vistazo [aquí](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values).

Comment: Unicamente estoy utilizando xampp, nose si sea correcto.